# Colexiographic ordering problem

Tags: combinatorics, infinitary-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

I have two vectors, $(b_1,\cdots,b_k)$ and $(ms_1,\cdots,ms_{2^k})$. Let $\overline{b_l} = (1-b_l)$ be the falsity term of $b_l$. As an example consider $k=3$, then the ordering I require is:

$m_1 = b_1b_2b_3$

$m_2 = b_1b_2\overline{b_3}$

$m_3 = b_1\overline{b_2}b_3$

$m_4 = \overline{b_1}b_2b_3$

$m_5 = b_1\overline{b_2}\overline{b_3}$

$m_6 = \overline{b_1}b_2\overline{b_3}$

$m_7 =\overline{b_1}\overline{b_2}b_3$

$m_8 = \overline{b_1}\overline{b_2}\overline{b_3}$.

What would be a formula for defining $1 \le j \le 8$?. What would a generalised formula be for $m_j$ such that $1 \le j \le 2^k$?. I have tried using binary, however, this ordering does not group the terms correctly into sets with the same number of false terms.

Comment: You want ordering by number of truths, and then to break ties what?

Comment: i want ordering by number of truths yes. However, I cannot find a way to order the terms that have the same number of truths within the overall ordering

Answer (score 1):

You can use a curious place-value system, where position $i$ (from the right, starting at $i=0$) gets place value, $N+2^i$ where $N$ is sufficiently large do dominate those powers of $2$, for instance $N=2^n$ if you are dealing with $n$ bits. You probably want to give truth the value $0$ and falsehood the value $1$, opposite to what is otherwise usual. Then you can order the resulting numbers naturally.

In the example you would have the following values, with $N=10\geq2^3$ (for human readability)
$$
\begin{matrix} & \textrm{digits} & \textrm{value}\\
m_1 & (0,0,0) & 0 \\
m_2 & (0,0,1) & 11 \\
m_3 & (0,1,0) & 12 \\
m_4 & (1,0,0) & 14 \\
m_5 & (0,1,1) & 23 \\
m_6 & (1,0,1) & 25 \\
m_7 & (1,1,0) & 26 \\
m_8 & (1,1,1) & 37 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: That is a great idea! Would you be able to provide a formula for $m_j$?

Comment: Your notation is reverse in a couple of ways (indexing of the $b_i$ starting with $b_1$ on the left rather than $b_0$ on the right, and truth being $b_i=1$ rather than $0$). Therefore I think the value associated to those truth values would be $\sum_{i=1}^k(1-b_i)(N+2^{k-i})$, where $N\geq2^k$ is fixed.